# Spread / Space Out the Values of Perlin Noise

Tags: algorithm, noise, perlin-noise, procedural-generation

I am working to create procedurally generated terrain using Perlin Noise. I have gotten it to work fairly well so far. However, the landscape produced seems more like a swampland with many smaller lakes and very few real oceans.
[image: Screenshot]

I currently have the value noise scale value, but it only zooms the map in. Thinking about Perlin Noise like a sin wave, dividing by a value should spread it out more, like increasing the period of the sin wave. However, this is all that happens when I add this and increase that value (period is currently set at 1.25 in this picture):

[image: Screenshot]

This is what it looks like if I increase the sea level:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I make it so that there are more larger oceans and, or is this simply a bad way of looking at it? Here is my map generation code (as is):

```
public static float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int seed, float scale, int octaves, float persistance, float lacunarity, 
    Vector2 offset, NormalizeMode normalizeMode, float normalizationEstimation) {

    float[,] noiseMap = new float[mapWidth,mapHeight];

    System.Random prng = new System.Random (seed);
    Vector2[] octaveOffsets = new Vector2[octaves];

    float maxPossibleHeight = 0;

    float amplitude = 1;
    float frequency = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < octaves; i++) {

        float offsetX = prng.Next (-100000, 100000) + offset.x;
        float offsetY = prng.Next (-100000, 100000) - offset.y;

        octaveOffsets [i] = new Vector2 (offsetX, offsetY);

        maxPossibleHeight += amplitude;
        amplitude *= persistance;

    }

    if (scale <= 0) {

        scale = 0.0001f;

    }

    float maxLocalNoiseHeight = float.MinValue;
    float minLocalNoiseHeight = float.MaxValue;

    float halfWidth = mapWidth / 2f;
    float halfHeight = mapHeight / 2f;

    for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {

            amplitude = 1;
            frequency = 1;
            float noiseHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < octaves; i++) {

                float sampleX = (x - halfWidth + octaveOffsets[i].x) / scale * frequency;
                float sampleY = (y - halfHeight + octaveOffsets[i].y) / scale * frequency; 

                float perlinValue = ((Mathf.PerlinNoise (sampleX, sampleY) / period) * 2 - 1);
                noiseHeight += perlinValue * amplitude;

                amplitude *= persistance;
                frequency *= lacunarity;

            }

            if (noiseHeight > maxLocalNoiseHeight) {

                maxLocalNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;

            } else if (noiseHeight < minLocalNoiseHeight) {

                minLocalNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;

            }

            noiseMap [x, y] = noiseHeight;

        }

    }

    for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {

            if (normalizeMode == NormalizeMode.Local) {

                noiseMap [x, y] = Mathf.InverseLerp (minLocalNoiseHeight, maxLocalNoiseHeight, noiseMap [x, y]);

            } else {

                float normalizedHeight = (noiseMap [x, y] + 1) / (2f * maxPossibleHeight / normalizationEstimation);
                noiseMap [x, y] = Mathf.Clamp(normalizedHeight, 0, int.MaxValue);

            }

        }

    }

    return noiseMap;

}
```

Comment: That would simply add more water to the map, however, I'll add a screenshot, because that is a good point.

Comment: I would say you need to increase your octave count - how many octaves are you using at present?

Comment: 5 currently, but from my understanding the number of octaves increases the "detail" of the noise. Nonetheless, I'll try to edit these values once I get back to my computer.

Comment: At 1, it basically created a binary landscape with either snow capped plateaus or ocean. At 2 it made really smooth mountain faces and increasing only increased the detail / bumpiness, not the size of oceans and land masses

Comment: You can have a second perlin noise map with a lower frequency. Wherever this map is higher than a value such as 0.8, you multiply the base height with it.